# maven artifact : x (managed from y)

Tags: dependencies, maven-3

[image]

I actually was expecting powermock version 1.5.6 via transitive dependencies in a project, but i get only 1.4.11. What does this mean?

Comment: As the comment says it has been defined by a dependencyManagement block in a parent pom or may be in the same pom.

Answer (score 6):

When resolving dependencies, Maven will prefer a version specified in the POM's  section over the version resolved from dependencies and transitive dependencies.

Note that  can be inherited from a parent POM.

See the Maven documentation on [Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more info.

Specifically, check the part of the page that starts as below for a detailed explanation.

> A second, and very important use of the dependency management section
>   is to control the versions of artifacts used in transitive
>   dependencies. As an example consider these projects:

Comment: This answer is clear and to the point. Thank you so much!