# Maven Dependency - Managed from Version?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

[image]

i am adding version 1.4.0 in my project. Still dependency tree shows that it is picking up 1.2.71. I am confused why this is happening and how we can resolve this?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373395/maven-artifact-x-managed-from-y) help you?

Answer (score 0):

The version you get is coming from the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM or your parent POM.

You can override this behaviour by adding a `<dependency>` entry to the ´` with the desired version.