# Maven version override over dependency management

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have the following app structure:

```
+- Parent
   +- Service
   +- Library A
   +- Library B

where [Library A] depends on [Library B]
and [Service] only includes [Library A]
```

**POM files**

*Parent*

```
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <!-- This brings in ES 7.12.1 which I'm trying to exclude or override in children -->
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

*Library A*

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-b</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
</dependencies>
```

*Library B*

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <!-- This version is in conflict with 7.12.1 brought in by spring-boot-dependencies -->
        <version>7.15.1</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

**What I want**

To upgrade elastic search in `Library B` to `7.15.1` and override the version in `Parent` (which is `7.12.1`, given by `spring-boot-dependencies`).

I want this newer version to show up in all places using this library (`Service`, in my example)

**Why**

ES `7.12.1` has some fixes resolved in latter versions; `spring-boot-dependencies` was not yet upgraded with newer ES

**What I've tried**

- Declaring a `<dependency>` in `Library B` with ES `7.15.1`
- Declaring a `<dependency>` in `Parent`'s dependency management section with ES `7.15.1` and including this in children
- Excluding ES from `spring-boot-dependencies` => [exclusion functionality not yet implemented in dependency management](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5600)

**Why it doesn't work**

Running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.elasticsearch` on `Library A` still looks like:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ eventer ---
[INFO] com.app:library-a:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] \- com.app:library-b:jar:1.0.0
[INFO]    +- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:jar:7.12.1:compile (version managed from 7.15.1)
[INFO]    |  \- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.12.1:compile - version managed from 7.15.1; omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.12.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-geo:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:7.12.1:compile
[INFO]       |  \- (org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:7.12.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]       +- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:5.7.0-1:compile
[INFO]       \- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-plugin-classloader:jar:7.12.1:runtime
```

**Possible ugly workaround**

Declare ES `7.15.1` in `Library B`, `Library A`, AND `Service`... lots of duplicate information, hard to maintain.

**References**

- [Import Dependency Management with Exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276024/import-dependency-management-with-exclusion)
- [Maven - version managed from x, omitted for duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572760/maven-version-managed-from-x-omitted-for-duplicate)
- [Maven Dependency - Managed from Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67123865/maven-dependency-managed-from-version)
- [Maven: how to override the dependency added by a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937195/maven-how-to-override-the-dependency-added-by-a-library)

Comment: Do `Project A` and `Project B` have `pom.xml` files? If so it would be very helpful to see them... furthermore do you use the `Parent` having a `pom.xml` with `dependencyManagement` ? (btw. Deleting `.m2/` will never help because it's cache. The issue is related to the pom files...

Comment: can you run `mvn depdency:tree -Dverbose` on project A and add the location to the answer where ES `7.12.1` not ignored?

Comment: @khmarbaise @Ruwanka Madhushan I've changed my question around a bit. Figured out this lower version is indeed coming from `parent`'s dependency management, but now I can't really override it.